# QGIS Features to polygons

Tags: qgis, features, topology

I would like to know if there is any equivalent on QGIS for the ArcGIS function 'Features to Polygons':

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-polygon.htm

The basic QGIS does not have it (There is a function called lines to polygons but it just closes the first and las vertex), but I wonder if there is any other way using a plugin, macro, python script or other free software to do the same as the ArcGIS 'Features to Polygons'.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Lines to Polygons and Polygonize are in the standard toolbox in QGIS [Processing>Toolbox]